# How to send python list to a C array of string and to a C array of long integers?

Tags: python, c, python-embedding

I have tried to send a python list to a C array of string/integers. And I tried to print the array of string but it is printing nothing.

I am actually writing code to extract data from a .csv file by using Python and trying to send this data to a C code.  When I am trying to run the code I am getting some warning.

I am calling this function from `main(){}` like `string_arr_conversion(NULL,pFunc)`, but I am not able to see any print and I am getting the warning which below explained.

I have debugged and found that `if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "o", &str_arr)) {retun NULL;}` when I am calling the function the above if block returning null.

```
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject *string_arr_conversion(PyObject *self,PyObject *args){
    PyObject *str_arr;
    int i;
    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "o", &str_arr)){
        retun NULL;
    }
    int n=PyObject_Length(str_arr);
        if(n<0) {
            return NULL;
        }
    char arr[n][40];
    for(i=0; i<n;i++){
        PyObject *str=PyList_GetItem(str_arr,i);
        arr[i][40]=PyLong_FromString(str,NULL,10);
    }
    for(i = 0; i<n; i++){
        printf("\n Element is %c", arr[i]);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

I am getting the following warnings:

```
1.In string_err_conversion function passing argument 1 of 'PyLong_FromString' from incompatible pointer type.  
note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'struct PyObject *'  
assignment makes integer from pointer without cast.{here            arr[i][MAX_STRING_SIZE]=PyLong_FromString(str,NULL,10); warnings are coming}  
2.return from incompatible pointer type and function returns address of local variable.{In this line ::return arr;}
```

Comment: To comunicate data, I suggest to use JSON standard. Maybe on read you have to cast some value to desired variable type

Comment: I do not have experience of working with JSON. And when I am calling the method the call is happening but the problem is it i going iside first if block of above function definition.